# UE4 Pawn Sensing

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Как сделать в UE4 чтоб бот мог видеть тебя на 360 градусов (грубо говоря, чтоб у него были глаза на затылке)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно повесть на вашего бота триггер, когда персонаж будет входить в зону действия триггера обрабатывать событие ботом.

Comment: Раз кто-то минусанул без пояснения причин, внешне логичный ответ, то ловите компенсационный плюс.

Comment: Спасибо Kromster!  Но раз минусанули значить знаю какой-то  другой способ... возможно через Raycast-ы,  но это больше затрат на производительность.

Comment: К сожалению вопрос очень размыт, поэтому самое простое решение - информировать бота обо всем, что попадает в радиус - что собственно вы и предлагаете, как я понимаю.

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли. Тем более в UE4  есть возможность выставить отработку триггеров на необходимые классы.  Так что мой вариант является довольно оптимальным.

Comment: Спасибо всем)!!

Answer (score 0):

В `UE4` существует специальный компонент, называется `UAIPerceptionComponent`, для него можно создавать определённые "чувства", такие как зрение, слух и т.п. Далее можно создать правило, влияющее на восприятие, например - Чувствовать противника за стеной, если расстояние составляет менее 2 меторов.
Вот ссылка на краткий `HowTo`: [Тык](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/quick-ai-perception-jumpstart-c/27452)